# Xpath reference for addressing array of elements in Selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-rc

I have 4 span elements with the same properties in a page. I tried to click on the fourth span with the below code:

```
selenium.click("css=span:contains('item12_21'):nth-child(4)");
```

But I am getting the error "element not found". I am trying to click the element with different workarounds, but no luck. I even tried to give the entire hierarchy, but I have a node called `#document` in between the tags. Please let me know how to handle the `#document` in Xpath.

I have IE 7 and the application is not compatible with Firefox, so I'm working with the IE developer toolbar. Can any one please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: You're getting "element not found" because there is no such CSS selector as ":contains".  It was ejected from the CSS3 spec years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The basic XPath will look like this:

```
//span[contains(., 'item12_21')]
```

Then (I'm not fully sure which one you want), you can get either the fourth item from that filtered list:

```
(//span[contains(., 'item12_21')])[4]
```

... or every item that is the fourth descendant like this:

```
//span[contains(., 'item12_21')][4]
```

The brackets indicate the precedence for the indexing.

I'm hoping the `#document` item will be bypassed using this, but if it isn't, you'll need to post some of your html to show the context of your items.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I am able to successfully click the element with the below code selenium.click("//div[4][contains(@id,'elMenu12')]/span[21][contains(@id,'item12_21')]");